# JHipster Master-Detail UI

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, jhipster

Is there a way to generate master-detail form in JHipster?

I have generated two entities:

- Order
- Item (many-to-one to Order)

and I would like to have CRUD for Items in the Order form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the CRUD code for both entities. You will need to change your controller and the template for your order so that you can be able to perform CRUD operation on item from the order page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But is there a way to generate it or get it done from available info? This would be preferred option, as one would avoid all merge work in case the model (ex. on Master) changes.

Comment: There is no such option as far as I know. But if you keep your code format consisten with the generated code from JHister then it is not a problem to manage the change  when generating the source code. I this way I can also keep trac of the changes that JHipster is dowing when I upgrade my JHipster version.

Comment: thank you! Can you share a link or example of master-detail? I'm still new to AngularJs...